# How to add a new visitortag to the current user (Sitecore)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms

I'm using Sitecore 6.6. I want to add a new visitortag to the current user in programcode (C#). Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Jordy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign tags to the current analytics visitor through the Analytics API:

```
Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Visitor.Tags.Add("MyTagName", "content of my tag");
```

To debug, you can check the *VisitorTags* table in the Analytics database but keep in mind that it might take a few moments until the tags are saved down to the database as Analytics saves them asynchronously.

Also keep in mind that Analytics is disabled during editing mode.

Answer (score 1):

The "Set" method acts as an Add/Update. Depending on whether the visitor is returning, or new, this could reduce code blocks needed.

> Tracker.Visitor.Tags.Set("YourTagName", "YourTagValue" );

By default, sitecore has a list of visitor tags, it uses for it's reports. (Email, First Name, Second Name, Company, Organization, Full Name, StateProvince). I found this out by looking at query used to build the visit reports "/sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Reports SQL Queries/Visits Visitor Tags". It reduced the amount of tags I thought I had to create.

Mark also has an awesome answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24488359/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-wffm-field-as-a-tag-and-output-it-in-a-sitecore-dms#) where he explains how to add custom visitor tags you create to the Visit Reports. If I had the rep I would up vote you Mark. It was a big help.