# How to implement tagging from WFFM in a multilingual site?

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore7.2, sitecore-mvc

We would like to use the Web Forms For Marketers "Tag visitor" functionality, using the standard pre-built tags available (see [How do I get the value of a WFFM field as a tag and output it in a Sitecore DMS report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24488359/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-wffm-field-as-a-tag-and-output-it-in-a-sitecore-dms) )

We have found, however, that instead of using item name of the field item as the key for a tag, Sitecore is using the value of the form-field item Title field. In a mutlilingual solution this makes WFFM tagging unworkable, as we need to be able to translate our field titles into languages as diverse as Chinese, Japanese, Turkish and Russian, as well as most European languages, and once translated the field titles no longer match the tag names.

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

EDIT: This appears to be a Web Forms For Marketers MVC issue, as there's no problem with this in our non-MVC site.

EDIT: This issue semms to be fixed with WFFM 2.4 rev. 150619

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitecore has confirmed this is a bug and have provided us with a patch to test.

EDIT: This issue semms to be fixed with WFFM 2.4 rev. 150619